# mercurial API: how do I get the 40 digit revision hash from incoming command?

Tags: python, mercurial, mercurial-api

I am using the python mercurial API in my project.

```
from mercurial import ui, hg, commands
from mercurial.node import hex

user_id = ui.ui()
hg_repo = hg.repository(user_id, '/path/to/repo')

hg_repo.ui.pushbuffer()
some_is_coming = commands.incoming(hg_repo.ui, hg_repo, source='default',
                                       bundle=None, force=False)
if some_is_coming:
    output = hg_repo.ui.popbuffer()

In [95]: output
Out[95]: 'comparing with ssh:host-name\nsearching for changes\nchangeset:   1:e74dcb2eb5e1\ntag:         tip\nuser:        that-is-me\ndate:        Fri Nov 06 12:26:53 2015 +0100\nsummary:     added input.txt\n\n'
```

Extracting the short node info `e74dcb2eb5e1` will be easy. What I really need, however, is the 40 digit hex revision id. Is there any way to retrieve this information without pulling the repo first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a template that provides the full node hash as part of its output. Also, `commands.incoming` returns a numeric error code, where zero indicates success. I.e. you need something like:

```
from mercurial import ui, hg, commands
from mercurial.node import hex

user_id = ui.ui()
hg_repo = hg.repository(user_id, '/path/to/repo')

hg_repo.ui.pushbuffer()
command_result = commands.incoming(hg_repo.ui, hg_repo, source='default',
    bundle=None, force=False, template="json")
if command_result == 0:
    output = hg_repo.ui.popbuffer()
    print output
```

Two more things: First, you'll also get diagnostic output ("comparing with ..."), which can be suppressed via `-q` (or `ui.setconfig("ui", "quiet", "yes")`). However, note that this option will also affect the default templates and you may have to provide your own one. Second, setting the environment variable `HGPLAIN` is recommended so that aliases and defaults from your `.hgrc` are ignored (see `hg help scripting`).

Alternatively, you can use the Mercurial [command server](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommandServer) as implemented in `hglib` (available via `pip install python-hglib`).

```
import hglib

client = hglib.open(".")
# Standard implementation of incoming, which returns a list of tuples.
# force=False and bundle=None are the defaults, so we don't need to
# provide them here.
print client.incoming(path="default")
# Or the raw command output with a custom template.
changeset = "[ {rev|json}, {node|json}, {author|json}, {desc|json}, {branch|json}, {bookmarks|json}, {tags|json}, {date|json} ]\n"
print client.rawcommand(["incoming", "-q", "-T" + changeset])
```

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for sharing! I managed to get the info by using ``peer``: ``peer = hg.peer(ui.ui(), {}, remote_host)`` and then ``node.hex(peer.lookup(short_hash)`` where ``short_hash = 'e74dcb2eb5e1'``. Which has its drawbacks of course.

Comment: Very interesting. I wonder: where is the |json formatting documented? My hg documentation doesn't seem to tell me (at least where I look)

Comment: @planetmaker: See `hg help scripting`. Note that the `json` and `xml` styles are experimental and may change in the future.

Comment: Oh ho. I never would have guessed that help topic either. Very nice read. Thanks a lot.